# Why does Eclipse display UTF-8 encoded files differently?

Tags: eclipse, encoding, utf-8, editor, copyright-display

Eclipse is configured to interpret text files as UTF-8 encoding.  Why does it not honor these settings in the Editor for *.properties files?

A text file named db.properties contains the 2-byte copyright character (302 251 octal).  The file appears to be interpreted as ASCII (or ISO-8859-1) instead of UTF-8 as configured...

```
$ od -bc db.properties | head -2
0000000   043 040 103 157 160 171 162 151 147 150 164 040 302 251 040 062
           #       C   o   p   y   r   i   g   h   t       ©  **       2
```

Here is a screenshot of the Eclipse editor with this file loaded.

[image]

If the file is simply renamed to db.txt, the copyright symbol is displayed properly.

[image]

This suggests that Eclipse is treating .properties files differently than plain text files, configured to be interpreted as UTF-8. Is there a way to configure Eclipse to treat .properties files as UTF-8?

Platforms...

Mac OSX 10.15.7

Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (includes Incubating components)

Version: 2021-12 (4.22.0)
Build id: 20211202-1639

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at
Preferences -> General -> Content types -> Java Properties File

The default encoding appears as `ISO-8859-1`.

Default encoding can be changed there.

Comment: Bingo!  I was able to set UTF-8 for Java Properties files and the Editor now works.  Thanks!